# Why does a respiring mitochondrion have less cristae?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, microbiology, mitochondria

I read the following-

> Number of cristae is more in resting-state of mitochondrion, but
> decreases with activity, hence less in the respiring state.

- cited: GK Pal, *Textbook of Medical Physiology*

After looking up a few sites, I was still unable to find out **why resting mitochondrion have more cristae**. Why is it so?

Based on [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167488906000450), the cristae undergo morphological changes in response to metabolic state and/or matrix volume (*cristae remodelling)*, but I don't think that explains why it does so.